# fragments issues on android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I need some help,

I have an activity whit a bottom. It serve to call a new fragment. When I open the fragment, this bottom into the activity still appear. What can I do to avoid this bottom appears in this activity? 
This is the fragment code:

```
    public class Publicacion1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_publicacion1, container, false);
    }
}
```

and this is the bottom code that calls the fragment and it is located in the activity:

```
public void publicacion1(View v){
        FragmentManager fragmentmanager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.emp,new Publicacion1()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Thanks for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

Add this `android:visibility="gone"` inside your Button in XML and in your Fragment

```
 Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourid);  
 btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and in your method

```
    public void publicacion1(View v){  
    btn.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
    FragmentManager fragmentmanager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.emp,new Publicacion1()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Hope it helps.